# ng-model weird behavior with Asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Below is drop down selection code :

```
<select ng-model="filter.area">
    <option value="">Select your location</option>
    <option ng-repeat="area in areaNames" value='{{ area.area_name }}'>{{ area.area_name }}</option>
</select>
```

`ng-model` is set in controller before Async function is called:

```
$scope.filter.area = $cookies['filterArea'];
// which evaluated to some value lets say 'Bole'
```

Now comes asynchronous function:

```
query.find({
   success: function(results_area) {
     $scope.$apply(function() {

        $scope.areaNames = results_area;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.areaNames.length; i++) {
          $scope.areaNames[i].area_name = $scope.areaNames[i].get('name');
        };

      });
   },
   error: function(error) {
      console.log("error in fetching area info....");
    }
   });
```

`ng-model` isn't updating. Any idea whats wrong here?

To see the demo go here : 
http://peppy-avatar-762.appspot.com/

Then select "Addis Ababa" and Select "Bole" as area then click on find food! Check area filter on left side. ng-model doesn't get updated!

Comment: Why do you do your assignment to the scope inside the provider function? I tend to assign element to my scope then only call ```$scope.$apply()``` after and it generally do the trick.

Comment: it doesn't do trick for me!

Comment: Are you sure the scope in your `ng-repeat` directive is looking at the same scope as your `query.find` is?

Comment: @DanPantry 100% sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the options are loaded lazily, use `ng-options` instead of using `ng-repeat` on `option`

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedItem" 
        data-ng-options="item for item in items track by item">
</select>
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/n22hlAk71BNMFOtC5nzC?p=preview)